# jQuery addclass when clicked and remove class when something else is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I'm building a photo frame designer. On it I want it so that when a pattern is clicked it fills the text with the pattern. I have achieved this using .addClass. Problem being that my .addClass stops my .css from working. Also I can't reclick it. To see what im talking about see [here](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame)

Here is my code

```
    $("#pattern1").click (function() {
        $('.text').addClass('background1');
    });

    $('#purple').click (function() {
            $(".border").css("fill", "#a077a6");
    });
```

Please don't ask for a js fiddle. Just use the website.

Comment: "Please don't ask for a js fiddle. Just use the website." ..Nice one.

Comment: haha yeah. I think you're not being sarcastic.

Comment: @thinkrite Try to use Id instead of Class name in $('.text').addClass('background1');, may be it works

Comment: your mean change the text class to an id class? Or use addId instead of addClass. Not even sure of addId is a thing

Comment: Change the .text to an ID so #text. And there is a second 
           `<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
               <p class="text">Your words here</p>
           </body>` body-Tag which should not be there..

Comment: @thinkrite i mean $('.text').addClass('background1'); in this line see .text is class name and instead of that use element id

Comment: it's exactly the same problem. Change the .text to #text makes no difference.

Comment: $(".border").css("fill", "#a077a6") what is fill here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'believe that the problem is that you add every time a class but the class will not be removed after clicking on an other pattern.
So I've just clicked on every Pattern and this is the changed source-code:

```
<p style="color: rgb(0, 51, 114);" class="text background2 background3 background4 background5 background1 background6 background7 background8 background9 background10 background11 background12">Your words here</p>
```

So simply JS don't know what to do with the background-classes.
Change the `<p>-Tag` to following:

```
<p id="text">Your words here</p>
```

and change every Function to:

```
  $("#patternXXX").click (function() {
      $('#text').removeClass();
      $('#text').addClass('backgroundXXX');
  });
```

So every class will be removed and the only needed class will be added.

Greetings

Comment: " the problem is that you add the classes but they aren't being deleted after selecting something else" - yes that's exactly the problem. What's wrong with the your words here? Ahh but the remove class could work. Let me try it. Thanks

Comment: @thinkrite Please clear out this, class add on click but it's not remove in other click? am i right?

Comment: Haha just some gibberish. My english is not so good LOL. Edited the code below. (And also the gibberish..)

Comment: it changes between the patterns which is the .addClass bit perfectly. Although the .css no longer works. I suppose I could change .css to .addClass but that would involve creating a load of classes.

Comment: When i select a pattern and change the Text-Color it works perfectly. Browser bug? Or should the pattern be removed by clicking on the Text-Color?

Comment: Yes the pattern should be replaced by the color.